# Show error message when clicked on the like button

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I want to make a like system using PHP and MySQL when clicked on the like Button i also insert Data in the database but there is an error database value inserted but like value as 0 no increment and undefined error occurs . Can anybody help me solving this problem

```
There is my Like button code :

<?php 
     //// work with like box 
      $get_likes = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `likes`");
      if (mysqli_num_rows($get_likes)===1) {

            $get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_likes);
           // $uid = $get['uid'];
            $total_likes = $get['total_likes'];
            //echo $uid;
            $total_likes =   $total_likes  + 1;
            //echo $total_likes++; 
        }   

    if (isset($_POST['likebutton_'])) {
      $like = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `likes` SET `total_likes`  = '$total_likes'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    //$insert_Data = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `likes` (`uid`) VALUES('$username')") or die(mysqli_error($ocn));
     header("Location:home.php");

    }

    else 
    {
      echo "Error";
    }
    ?>
    this code work fine without insert Data
    There is My liked with Data Insertd Code 
     <?php 
     ////work with like box 
      $get_likes = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `likes`");
      if (mysqli_num_rows($get_likes)===1) {

            $get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_likes);
           // $uid = $get['uid'];
            $total_likes = $get['total_likes'];
            //echo $uid;
            $total_likes =   $total_likes  + 1;
            //echo $total_likes++; 
        }   

    if (isset($_POST['likebutton_'])) {
      $like = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `likes` SET `total_likes`  = '$total_likes'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $insert_Data = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `likes` (`uid`) VALUES('$username')") or die(mysqli_error($ocn));
     header("Location:home.php");

    }

    else 
    {
      echo "Error";
    }
    ?>
    this is output i want to display my font-end page <?php echo $total_likes ;?> but it occur error

    The error is Undefined Variable 
I also try $total_likes=""; 
as global but still not work
```

Comment: Can you add your code for the form, database and the front-end page you would like to display the result on?

Comment: You don't need to get the `likes` just have `mysql` update the current row + 1. You are open to SQL injections with this code. Also shouldn't you be passing some ID so you don't update every record?

Comment: The issue you are encountering my guess is that  `mysqli_num_rows($get_likes)` doesn't equal `1`. You only assign `$total_likes` if the count is 1.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your code suffers from a race condition. What you should be doing is this pattern:

```
INSERT INTO likes (uid, total_likes) VALUES (?, 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY SET total_likes=total_likes+1
```

Where you use `bind_param` to set the placeholder value to your UID.

Note that in your one query you set the total count of *all* likes to be +1. This is a huge mistake.